# Why does Visual Studio only expose part of the Environent.SpecialFolder enumeration?

Tags: .net, visual-studio

The .Net documentation shows the Environment.SpecialFolder enumeration to be extensive, and to apply to all versions of the framework up to and including 4.0.
But when I attempted to use it in Visual Studio 2010 Professional, I found that intellisense did not recognise its CommonDocuments member. I used the context menu to "Go To Definition", whereupon it opened a new tab called "Environment [from metadata]" which showed the SpecialFolder enumeration as follows:

```
    // Summary:
    //     Specifies enumerated constants used to retrieve directory paths to system
    //     special folders.
    [ComVisible(true)]
    public enum SpecialFolder
    {
        // Summary:
        //     The logical Desktop rather than the physical file system location.
        Desktop = 0,
        //
        // Summary:
        //     The directory that contains the user's program groups.
        Programs = 2,
        //
        // Summary:
        //     The directory that serves as a common repository for documents.
        Personal = 5,
        //
        // Summary:
        //     The "My Documents" folder.
        MyDocuments = 5,
        //
        // Summary:
        //     The directory that serves as a common repository for the user's favorite
        //     items.
        Favorites = 6,
        //
        // Summary:
        //     The directory that corresponds to the user's Startup program group.
        Startup = 7,
        //
        // Summary:
        //     The directory that contains the user's most recently used documents.
        Recent = 8,
        //
        // Summary:
        //     The directory that contains the Send To menu items.
        SendTo = 9,
        //
        // Summary:
        //     The directory that contains the Start menu items.
        StartMenu = 11,
        //
        // Summary:
        //     The "My Music" folder.
        MyMusic = 13,
        //
        // Summary:
        //     The directory used to physically store file objects on the desktop.
        DesktopDirectory = 16,
        //
        // Summary:
        //     The "My Computer" folder.
        MyComputer = 17,
        //
        // Summary:
        //     The directory that serves as a common repository for document templates.
        Templates = 21,
        //
        // Summary:
        //     The directory that serves as a common repository for application-specific
        //     data for the current roaming user.
        ApplicationData = 26,
        //
        // Summary:
        //     The directory that serves as a common repository for application-specific
        //     data that is used by the current, non-roaming user.
        LocalApplicationData = 28,
        //
        // Summary:
        //     The directory that serves as a common repository for temporary Internet files.
        InternetCache = 32,
        //
        // Summary:
        //     The directory that serves as a common repository for Internet cookies.
        Cookies = 33,
        //
        // Summary:
        //     The directory that serves as a common repository for Internet history items.
        History = 34,
        //
        // Summary:
        //     The directory that serves as a common repository for application-specific
        //     data that is used by all users.
        CommonApplicationData = 35,
        //
        // Summary:
        //     The System directory.
        System = 37,
        //
        // Summary:
        //     The program files directory.
        ProgramFiles = 38,
        //
        // Summary:
        //     The "My Pictures" folder.
        MyPictures = 39,
        //
        // Summary:
        //     The directory for components that are shared across applications.
        CommonProgramFiles = 43,
    }
```

As you can see, it both skips values as it works through its list of members and it stops at CommonProgramFiles. The documentation shows 47 members of this enumeration, whereas Visual Studio shows it to contain only 23 members.

Can anyone explain this discrepancy and what I need to do to correct it please?

Michael

Comment: Michael, you should edit your display name to be Michael, and not include that extra line in your posts.

Comment: What version of the framework is your project targeting?

Comment: Sorry Jon - it's 2.0.

Answer (score 2):

> it's 2.0

That's a version of .NET that still supports Windows 98 and 2000.  Ancient operating systems that didn't have as many common folders.  In general a problem in .NET, it tries to be agnostic of operating system versions but that does make it hard to take advantage of newer OS features.

The enum was extended in .NET 4.0, possible because it dropped support for Windows 2000.

Do take this as an unsubtle hint that targeting .NET 2.0 no longer makes any sense.  The odds you'll find a customer that actually requires it are miniscule.  And highly doubtful you'll want to support him when he's got a Windows 98 or 2000 specific problem.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it 32bit and 64 bit have some differences, as well as the framework version. My 4.0.0.0 version on a x64 has these options that hint at that:

```
        //
        // Summary:
        //     The directory for components that are shared across applications.To get the
        //     x86 common program files directory on a non-x86 system, use the System.Environment.SpecialFolder.ProgramFilesX86
        //     member.
        CommonProgramFiles = 43,
        //
        // Summary:
        //     The Program Files folder. Added in the .NET Framework 4.
        CommonProgramFilesX86 = 44,
        //
        // Summary:
        //     The file system directory that contains the templates that are available
        //     to all users. This special folder is valid only for Windows NT systems. Added
        //     in the .NET Framework 4.
        CommonTemplates = 45,
        //
        // Summary:
        //     The file system directory that contains documents that are common to all
        //     users. This special folder is valid for Windows NT systems, Windows 95, and
        //     Windows 98 systems with Shfolder.dll installed. Added in the .NET Framework 4.
        CommonDocuments = 46,
        //
        // Summary:
        //     The file system directory that contains administrative tools for all users
        //     of the computer. Added in the .NET Framework 4.
        CommonAdminTools = 47,
```

More info on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev12.query?appId=Dev12IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28System.Environment.SpecialFolder%29;k%28SolutionItemsProject%29;k%28SolutionItemsProject%29;k%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.1%29;k%28DevLang-csharp%29&rd=true). Try changing framework version and see how it changes

Comment: Thanks for the responses guys. Yes, it appears that the full set of members of this enumeration is only available from V4.0 onwards. This means that the Microsoft documentation is misleading. I won't say that it is wrong, because the enumeration itself does exist from V1.0 onwards, but I don't see it state anywhere which members of the enumeration are available in which releases of the framework.

Incidentally, I always prefer to use the lowest common denominator technology available because it both provides the widest coverage and invariably runs the fastest.